# IOS Chat App unread Messages in UITableview cell

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a Query related to Chat Application like Whatsapp. How to Calculate total number of Unread messages by friends in chat app like whatsapp. if we want to calculate all unread messages and show on a badge in current chat window only?

Comment: To get the most help from this site you should show the code you have attempted and show what you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you model the conversations or without any code provided by you it's difficult to give you an exact answer but let's imagine a possible way to model it assuming you still haven't implemented nothing.

You could use a Message object class (or struct if using swift) to hold each conversation entry which could hold among other properties: message text, the User object owing the message, other relevant info etc and a property to determine if it was read (e.g. isRead Boolean property or an enum type .read .unread).

A Conversation object could be a List (an Array) of Message objects and if you want to know how many messages on a conversation are unread (to update UI, badge or whatever other UI widget you need to update) it would be a matter of filtering a given Conversation instance and counting the amount of Message objects inside of it that have isRead==false or whose status is .unread if you go the enum way.

This is a simplistic approach and may (or not) match your current implementation but as no code was provided by you, let's consider this an 'educated guess'.